# How to remove chrome sleeve from copper pipe on vanity?

Tags: faucet

[image][image]enter image description hereI am getting ready to replace the vanity in our older home. The problem I have is how do I remove the chrome sleeve from the pipe so I can attach fittings to the copper pipe. This looks like a compression fitting. Is the sleeve attached to the fitting or compressed up inside. I would like to use the same pipe just remove the sleeve. How can I remove the sleeve without damaging the copper pipe. The pipe can be cut, there is about 2 ft between the floor and the fawcett. If I cut the pipe with the tube cutter will I be able to remove the sleeve? Anyone have experience with these? The sleeves are new to me. Thanks

[image]

Comment: I've not seen anything like that, but I would say just cut the pipe twice and remove a small section of it. So that you can then get in there to loosen the rest without risk bending the copper.

Comment: Why aren't you able to cut it all off and add a compression fitting or valve to the copper that remains?

Comment: This bathroom is on the 2nd floor above the kitchen. There are no shutoffs on the line (to be installed) The sleeve ends in the floor/kitchen ceiling. Plumbing is exposed across the kitchen ceiling. I could cut the pipe somewhere in the ceiling pipes, install a shutoff and replace the feed pipes to the sink. However I would like to avoid having to expose the shutoffs on the kitchen ceiling( will if I have to) and keep them in the vanity closet.

Answer (score 1):

Answered by OP in a comment:

> Thanks to all who presented their ideas and theories. I did the job today . It turned out that they were brass /chrome plated pipes not sleeves at all. They were threaded on the bottom and the joint was between the floors out of sight. They just wound out with vice grips. This would be original plumbing installed in the late 1940s and still going strong. My Mrs just wanted it updated. Methods have sure changed our the last 80 years.Thanks all .Job complete. – *jer prime Dec 8 '17 at 21:26*

Answer (score 0):

Is the other end of the copper pipe attached to a valve?

Typically you would remove the old supply line from the valve to the sink and install new if needed.

You are going to have to cut the copper if you do not have threaded connection on the other end, so if you do not have a valve then you should install one so you can turn off the water in the event of a faucet failure or replacement.

Comment: No valve on the lines. Shut offs to be added. Yes Im hoping to be able to cut a foot above the floor, be able to remove the sleeves, add shutoffs and fittings  to the copper and flexible feed to the facets.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that is chrome I think it is a sweated fitting that the solder flowed over the edge when soldering the connection. If you can drain the line you could heat it with a torch and disassemble. I like using map gas over propane because it is hotter, but a standard propane torch will work with no water in the line. If there is not a shut off valve I would probably install one then use a flex line instead of hard line a lot easier.

Comment: The sleeve appears to be brass /chrome plated. Draining is no problem. You could be right that its sweated, thou I see no signs of soldering.

Comment: Sweated is soldering for the last 35 years we have used a No lead solder but this is comnly referred to as sweated.

Comment: Thanks to all who presented their ideas and theories. I did the job today . It turned out that they were brass /chrome plated pipes not sleeves at all. They were threaded on the bottom and the joint was between the floors out of sight. They just wound out with vice grips. This would be original plumbing installed in the late 1940s and still going strong. My Mrs just wanted it updated. Methods have sure changed our the last 80 years.Thanks all .Job complete.